# Conditional distribution calculation

Tags: probability

I'm trying to solve this question (Answer provided).
[image: Q&A]

I suspect that c) has ERROR in the answer. 
My answer is: $\mathbb{P}(X=k\mid Y=2) = \frac{2}{10}$
Because that if $Y=2$ then the maximum from both notes is 2. Then $X=k$ can be $X=1$ or $X=2$. Each on prob $\frac{1}{10}$.

I'm not sure at my answer, but I think that the answer provided is wrong because if $k=2$ ($k>1$) the probability $\mathbb{P}(x=2, y=2)\neq 0$

Comment: P(X=1|Y=2) = 2/3 and P(X=2|Y=2) = 1/3 and zero elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, given $Y=2$, we can only have $X=1$ or $2$. By definition,
$$\mathbb P(X=1|Y=2)=\frac{\mathbb P(X=1,Y=2)}{\mathbb P(Y=2)}.$$
Notice that 
$$\mathbb P(Y=2)=\frac{3}{100},$$
because there are in total $100$ equally likely outcomes, while only **three** satisfy our requirement: $(1,2)$, $(2,1)$, and $(2,2)$. (Notice that we do not know which number, from the first hat or the second, will be the greatest/smallest!) Also notice that by a similar logic,
$$\mathbb P(X=1,Y=2)=\frac{2}{100},$$
since only **two** outcomes satisfy your requirement: $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$. Thus, $\mathbb P(X=1|Y=2)=2/3$, and hence $\mathbb P(X=2|Y=2)=1-2/3=1/3$.